# Extending Credentials Plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i want to extend Jenkins Credential Plugin and add one more additional custom option,
I couldn't find a valid place to start with, neither jenkins has a good resource on this nor a third party documentation.

Comment: I was about to post the same, hope we get an answer

Comment: So what do you want from a new option type?

Comment: Assume an option "Certificate"
Under that i have an option to upload file, i want to validate that extension as soon as he uploads it, if valid save it else throw error

Comment: There is this as a starting point https://plugins.jenkins.io/plain-credentials which might help. I don't think it validates the file but its a start